# Meaning of Splitrule in random forest model

Tags: machine-learning, caret

I am running a random forest model with the caret package and get the following as output:

```
No pre-processing
Resampling: Rolling Forecasting Origin Resampling (1 held-out with no fixed window) 
Summary of sample sizes: 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  splitrule   RMSE      Rsquared  MAE     
  variance    9.515708  NaN       9.515708
  extratrees  9.674571  NaN       9.674571

Tuning parameter 'mtry' was held constant at a value of 3
RMSE was used to select the optimal model using  the smallest value.
The final values used for the model were mtry = 3 and splitrule = variance.
```

What does split rule = variance and split rule = extratrees mean? Does anyone have an explanation or literature I can refer to? I'm having trouble finding an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The caret package does not implement the random forest algorithm itself, it calls external functions. In this case I guess it calls the [ranger package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ranger/ranger.pdf).

Together with the most traditional splitting rules like [gini, information gain or variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning#Metrics) also allows to consider extra trees as splitting rule, described [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.65.7485&rep=rep1&type=pdf), which basically "splits nodes by choosing cut-points fully at random".